# Confusing SWT Style Bits in CSS Spy

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-pde

[image]

The **CSS Rules** section of **CSS Spy** shows the current **SWT Style Bits** for the selected control, but it seems to contain a lot of useless information, such as styles that are not currently supported by the selected control(e.g. `SWT.RADIO`), and bits that are not styles(e.g. `SWT.ERROR_MENU_NOT_POP_UP`). Why is it designed this way, and what is the use of these ?

Comment: Many style bits share the same value - SWT.RADIO is the same as SWT.RESIZE for example - the spy cannot tell which one is correct for the control so shows all of them. SWT.ERROR_MENU_NOT_DROP_DOWN just looks wrong and could possibly be reported as a bug. The code is `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.helpers.SWTStyleHelpers`

Comment: For the **SWT Style Bits** part, I think it was intended to make it easy for users to write CSS selectors like `Shell [style~='SWT.RESIZE']`. But `SWT.RADIO` with the same value is now shown, which requires the user to make an extra judgement by experience, and this part of Spy's functionality is not friendly at all.

Comment: Incidentally, with regard to collating all the styles supported by a given control, the way I'm doing it is:
1. the style bits listed in the styles section of the control's class document;
2. the style bits listed in the styles section of the control's parent control class document, but some of them may not be supported, and then verify them one by one;
Is there a better way?

Comment: Because the values are the same it doesn't matter if you use the wrong name in the CSS it will still work.